# How to use Group By correclty?

Tags: mysql

I have this query that worked fine:

```
select  isnull(email,'') as Email ,isnull([ERPM First Name],'')+' '+isnull([ERPM Last Name],'')[User Name],
    geo,CustomerID,BusinessID,courseid, MIN (CompletionDate) [1st Training Course],

CASE WHEN   COURSEID IN (37445,37644,37443,37778,37435,37733,37584,37483,37392,37817,
            37259,37597,37391,37393,37792,37816,37256,37257,37258,37484,37485,37486)
            THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' 
        END AS [Is it a campaing course?],

CASE WHEN   CompletionDate BETWEEN '2017-03-10' AND '2017-09-03' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
        END AS [During Campaign],

CASE WHEN COURSEID IN (37256,37257,37258,37484,37485,37486) AND 
            CompletionDate BETWEEN '2017-03-10' AND '2017-09-03' THEN 'ON Period Bonus' ELSE '-'
        END AS [1st BONUS]

from vw_Training_Cube
    where [Is disti or subdisti?] = 'No' and  [Is test account?] = 'No'
    and Email<>'0'
GROUP BY isnull(email,''),isnull([ERPM First Name],'')+' '+isnull([ERPM Last Name],''),geo,CustomerID,BusinessID,courseid,
CASE WHEN COURSEID IN (37445,37644,37443,37778,37435,37733,37584,37483,37392,
37817,37259,37597,37391,37393,37792,37816,37256,37257,37258,37484,37485,37486) 
THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' 
END,
CASE WHEN CompletionDate BETWEEN '2017-03-10' AND '2017-09-03' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
END,
CASE WHEN COURSEID IN (37256,37257,37258,37484,37485,37486) AND 
            CompletionDate BETWEEN '2017-03-10' AND '2017-09-03' THEN 'ON Period Bonus' ELSE '-5'
END
```

but now instead of grouping by email, I want to group by business id. But simply swapping the order doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: Suggestion, possibly create a sub-query that does all the data cleaning/formatting/transformations then an outer query that does aggregation. You won't have your CASE repeated in the group by and it should be easier to see what's going on

Comment: what is incorrect? the results? what did you expect as a result? the `GROUP BY` clause will form rows that are unique for *the whole set of columns* you have specified. i.e. if you reduce the columns in the select and group by clauses you will also get fewer rows (or vice-versa). Note too because you are not using any aggregate functions you could just use `select distinct` and remove the group by clause, and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need an aggregate function such as COUNT() MIN() or MAX() then you can simplify your query by using `select distinct`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      ISNULL(email, '')   
      AS Email
    , ISNULL([ERPM First Name], '') + ' ' + ISNULL([ERPM Last Name], '')
      [User Name]
    , geo
    , CustomerID
    , BusinessID
    , courseid
    , MIN(CompletionDate) [1st Training Course]
    , CASE
            WHEN COURSEID IN (37445, 37644, 37443, 37778, 37435, 37733, 37584, 37483, 37392, 37817,
            37259, 37597, 37391, 37393, 37792, 37816, 37256, 37257, 37258, 37484, 37485, 37486) THEN
                        'Yes'
            ELSE
                  'No'
      END                 AS [Is it a campaing course?]
    , CASE
            WHEN CompletionDate BETWEEN '2017-03-10' AND '2017-09-03' THEN
                        'Yes'
            ELSE
                  'No'
      END                 AS [During Campaign]
    , CASE
            WHEN COURSEID IN (37256, 37257, 37258, 37484, 37485, 37486) AND
            CompletionDate BETWEEN '2017-03-10' AND '2017-09-03' THEN
                        'ON Period Bonus'
            ELSE
                  '-'
      END                 AS [1st BONUS]

FROM vw_Training_Cube
WHERE [Is disti or subdisti?] = 'No'
AND [Is test account?] = 'No'
AND Email <> '0'
ORDER BY BusinessID
```

To reduce the rows further, you also need to remove columns - OR - start using aggregate functions. e.g. the following would produce the minimum set of rows to list every BusinessID that meets the where conditions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      BusinessID
FROM vw_Training_Cube
WHERE [Is disti or subdisti?] = 'No'
AND [Is test account?] = 'No'
AND Email <> '0'
ORDER BY BusinessID
;
```

Keep adding columns to that to see the effect on number of rows.